# Socket Failing to finish sending 4Byte Packets

Tags: java, sockets, loops, udp, filestream

This is more a follow up to a previous question asked earlier however I have modified my original code now, to be able to send a file Instead of text) via a UDP socket with a specific packet size. The program runs perfectly if I specify a 1, 2 or 4 byte packet, however if I try for anything larger, such as a 8, 16 etc, the program grinds to a halt. No exception is thrown in the console, however Netbeans shows a tiny warning symbol in the bottom right hand corner and shows the following.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Contents must be presorted - added value 42318 is less   than preceding value 42320
at org.netbeans.core.output2.IntList.add(IntList.java:76)
at org.netbeans.core.output2.AbstractLines.addTabAt(AbstractLines.java:1122)
at org.netbeans.core.output2.OutWriter.doWrite(OutWriter.java:452)
at org.netbeans.core.output2.OutWriter.write(OutWriter.java:506)
at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:456)
at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:473)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.ForkedJavaOverride$Copier.maybeFlush(ForkedJavaOverride.java:350)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.ForkedJavaOverride$Copier.access$000(ForkedJavaOverride.java:251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.ForkedJavaOverride$Copier$1.run(ForkedJavaOverride.java:271)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1432)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2044)
```

Is this error thrown because of the UDP Packets being received out of order by any chance? Is there a way to ignore this? I can tell the program has ceased as the string of "The End" does not appear. Does anyone know why this may be? My code for my client socket is attached below (its a bit of a long one and lots of comments for my own sanity). Many thanks in advance for any guidance.

```
public class UDPClient extends variable {

// static Integer portNo = 4444; 

static Integer byteSize = 16;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { //taken out main from here
    SocketForm form = new SocketForm();
    File file=null;

  long startTime; // Starting time of program, in milliseconds.
  long endTime;   // Time when computations are done, in milliseconds.
  double time;  

    //get server address
    String serverName = "localhost";

    if (args.length >= 1)
        serverName = args[0];
  InetAddress serverIPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverName);

    //get server port;
    int serverPort = form.cliportNo;
    if (args.length >= 2)
        serverPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    //create socket
    DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    //get input from keybaord
    byte[] sendData = new byte[byteSize];
    //BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    //while (true){
    //String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //sendData = sentence.getBytes();

    String fileName = "/Users/Andrew/Desktop/pic.jpg";
    File f = new File(fileName);

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        System.out.println("Total file size to read in bytes is : " + fis.available());

    } catch (IOException e) {}


Path path = Paths.get("/Users/Andrew/Desktop/pic.jpg");
//byte[] data = Fles.readAllBytes(path);
sendData = Files.readAllBytes(path);   

    try {
    for( int index = 0; index < sendData.length ; index += byteSize ) {
     DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( sendData, index, Math.min( byteSize, sendData.length-index ), serverIPAddress, serverPort);
     clientSocket.send(packet);
    //DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, serverIPAddress, serverPort);

    //receive datagram
    byte[] receiveData = new byte [byteSize];

    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
    //print output
    String sentenceFromServer = new String(receivePacket.getData());
    System.out.println("From Server:" + sentenceFromServer);
    }
    System.out.println("The End");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
    //close client socket
            //clientSocket.close();
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  time = endTime - startTime;
      System.out.println("Time :" + time);
   // }

} //end of main

} //end of UDPClient
```

Comment: IllegalArguementException could be a Netbeans Issue! Check this out http://statistics.netbeans.org/exceptions/exception.do?id=640314

Comment: I did think something similar and also came across that link, but surely if that was the case and it was a netbeans issue, would the program not respond the same way and freeze when sending 1, 2 and 4 Byte size packets? Just don't understand what's so special about a larger packet...

Comment: Have you tried to debug your program and see where it is halting?

Comment: I have tried to execute the netbeans debugger on the above code, however, it has returned nothing. My thread, main, java2d queue flusher and awt-eventqueue all show as running, but there is no data coming back on the results.

Comment: I guess you can not set breakpoints, otherwise I would try to debug with one breakpoint in this line `clientSocket.send(packet);` and see if at least your loop is working as expected. And besides if I were you I would try to use wireshark or tcpdump just to make sure you are sending or receiving data. Sorry this is all I can imagine in order to solve your problem.

Comment: Amazingly, its fixed!! Turns out it was a known bug with Netbeans and the latest revision addressed it. Downlaoded the latest copy of netbeans and it works perfectly now for all packet sizes. First thing monday morning I’m gonna storm into work and DEMAND that our netbeans installation is updated! Many thanks for your help and suggesstions.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Was running 7.3 of Netbeans. It is a known issue in 7.3 and has been addressed in the latest revision of 7.4. Solution : Update to Netbeans 7.4. Now purring like a cat. Thanks to all those who tried to help with this!